# React: cannot read property 'border' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make the borders of input boxes change colour if upon attempting to submit the form they are empty. However, when I try to do this I am receiving the error, "TypeError: Cannot set property 'border' of undefined". How can I fix this?

```
const [state, setState] = useState({from_name: '', from_email: '', message: ''});

const checkForm = (e) => {
    const stateLength = Object.keys(state).length;
    e.preventDefault();
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(state)){
        if(!value){
            const x = document.getElementsByName(key);
            x.style.border = "2px solid red";

        }
    }
}

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    console.log(state);


}

<Form onSubmit={checkForm}>
                <div className="form">
                    <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Name" name="from_name" />
                </div>
                <div className="form">
                    <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Email" name="from_email" />
                </div>
                <div className="form">
                    <textarea onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Message" rows="10" name="message" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   const x = document.getElementsByName(key);
    x.style.border = "2px solid red";
```

The problem here is that getElementsByName gives you a collection, not a single element.

You can treat the collection as an array to a certain extent. So you can get the first entry with [0]

Answer (score 1):

because document.getElementsByName (key) return **HTMLCollection** you can accses element with **x[0]**

another solution beside --  **x[0]**

---

```
  const [error, setError] = useState(null) 
    // and when you need to raise an error 
    
    setError("erro")
    
    // and you can make a simple css class with red border 
     .error{ border: 1px soild red} 
    
    // in jsx you can do some thing like thats
     
   <textarea onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Message" 
      rows="10" name="message" className={error ? "error": ""} />
```